# trying to use parseFloat to get rid of ending characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The script returns the state name and miles i.e. `TN  71.6 mi`.  I'm trying to get rid of the `mi` by converting the string to a number which should ignore the unwanted characters. The `parseFloat` command gets completely ignored.

```
function compileMilesReciever(data) {
    if (data === null) {
        setTimeout(compileMiles, 6000);
    } else {
        if (compileMilesIndex == orderedLatLngs.length) {

            if (!stepEndState) {
                stepEndState = startState;
            }

            stateMiles[stepEndState] = data.routes[0].legs[0].distance["text"];

            var txt = "";
            var i = 0;                   
            var x = stateMiles[state];
            parseFloat(x);

            for (state in stateMiles) {
                i++;
                $("#results").append
                $(".state" + i).append(state);
                $(".mile" + i).append(stateMiles[state]);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseFloat` returns a value, which you are not capturing.

```
var ret = parseFloat(x);
```

When you have an issue like this. Try running functions in your browser's Javascript console. You can usually figure out what is wrong on your own.

Comment: tried all 3 of the suggestions, none  worked. when i look at the console, it shows no errors at all  .....  it just seems to ignore the parseFloat.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're not using the value returned by `parseFloat`. To use it, you need:

```
x = parseFloat(x)
```

But this will fail, because `" mi"` is not a numerical value.

Instead, to ignore the `" mi"`, you can do something like:

```
x = parseFloat(x.substring(0, x.length - 3));
```

Comment: parseFloat really does ignore the extra characters. But it IS bad practice to pass it garbage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of mi only and keep the state than it's easier for you to use slice method:

```
console.log('TI 1563.12 mi'.slice(0, -3));
```